# JavaScript - prototype not returning functions - this.registerSelectors() is not a function - no Constructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In our VS solution project, there are about 50 different JS files. What I am doing is moving the code out of these files (Require.js was used in these separated files) and combining all the code into one larger single JS file. Reason for this is to reduce the requests from the website.

Nonetheless, I am receiving 1 of 2 errors, depending on if I wrap the JS functions/prototypes w/ a self-containing function.

The code uses jQuery and jQuery.UI

First error (**if wrapped**) is `FormBuilderDatePicker is not a constructor`

Second error (**if not wrapped**) is `this.registerSelectors is not a function`

Calling JS code:

```
        var quoteModuleObjArr = [
            { formId: "quote-module-form-moving", className: '.zipcode-moving', moveType: 'moving' },
            { formId: "quote-module-form-storage", className: '.zipcode-storage', moveType: 'storage' },
            { formId: "quote-module-form-moving-storage", className: '.zipcode-moving-storage', moveType: 'moving-storage' }
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < quoteModuleObjArr.length; i++) {

            var formBuilder = null;
            formBuilder = new FormBuilderDatePicker({
                datepicker: '#' + quoteModuleObjArr[i].formId + ' input.isDatePicker',
                formId: '#' + quoteModuleObjArr[i].formId
            });
        }
```

FormBuilderDatePicker function/prototype (wrapped):

```
var FormBuilderDatePicker = (function () {  // remove for the 2nd error (unwrapped)
        
        function FormBuilderDatePicker(options) {
            this.options = options;
            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaults, this.options);
            this.registerSelectors();
            this.delegateEvents()
        };

        FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.defaults = {
            datepicker: ".hasDatePicker",
            disabledDays: [],
            datepickerOptions: {
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: "+12M"
            },
            formId: ''
        };
        FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.registerSelectors = function () {
            this.options.$datepicker = $(this.options.datepicker);
        };
        FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.delegateEvents = function () {

            var _self = this;
            this.options.$datepicker.on("error", function () {
                var selectedDate = _self.options.$datepicker.val();
                _self.options.disabledDays.push(selectedDate)
            });
            this.options.$datepicker.on("change", function () {
                $(this).valid()
            });
            this.options.datepickerOptions.beforeShowDay = function (date) {

                var today = new Date;
                var todayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", today);
                var selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date);

                var notToday = todayDate != selectedDate;
                var isDisabledDay = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate("m/d/yy", date), _self.options.disabledDays) == -1;
                var result = notToday && isDisabledDay;

                if (notToday == false) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    }, 0);

                    return [result, "ui-datepicker-current-day"];
                }

                return [result];
            };

            this.options.datepickerOptions.onChangeMonthYear = function (year, month, datepicker) {

            }

            this.options.$datepicker.datepicker(this.options.datepickerOptions);
        };

        return FormBuilderDatePicker; // remove for the 2nd error (unwrapped)
    })();                             // remove for the 2nd error (unwrapped)
```

I have also tried creating an `init function`, that calls `FormBuilderDatePicker.registerSelectors()` and `FormBuilderDatePicker.delegateEvents()`, and removed the last (2) lines within the constructor, but I get the same error, that `registerSelectors()` is not a function (same w/ `delagateEvents()`.

I've also read that for prototypes to have the ability to be called, they need a `return` within the function. Hence, during testing, I added a `return true;` to the `delegateEvents` and `registerSelectors` functions, but this did not work either.

All code above is inside a `$(function() {});`

---

**Updated Code/Solution:**

```
    setupFormBuilderDatePicker();
    setupQuoteModuleDatePicker();

    // ***********************************************
    //  Quote Module Date Picker
    // ***********************************************

    var FormBuilderDatePicker;
    function setupFormBuilderDatePicker() {
        FormBuilderDatePicker = (function () {

            function FormBuilderDatePicker(options) {
                this.options = options;
                this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaults, this.options);
                this.registerSelectors();
                this.delegateEvents()
            };

            FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.defaults = {
                datepicker: ".hasDatePicker",
                disabledDays: [],
                datepickerOptions: {
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: "+12M"
                },
                formId: ''
            };
            FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.registerSelectors = function () {
                this.options.$datepicker = $(this.options.datepicker);
            };
            FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.delegateEvents = function () {

                var _self = this;
                this.options.$datepicker.on("error", function () {
                    var selectedDate = _self.options.$datepicker.val();
                    _self.options.disabledDays.push(selectedDate)
                });
                this.options.$datepicker.on("change", function () {
                    $(this).valid()
                });
                this.options.datepickerOptions.beforeShowDay = function (date) {

                    var today = new Date;
                    var todayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", today);
                    var selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date);

                    var notToday = todayDate != selectedDate;
                    var isDisabledDay = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate("m/d/yy", date), _self.options.disabledDays) == -1;
                    var result = notToday && isDisabledDay;

                    if (notToday == false) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                        }, 0);

                        return [result, "ui-datepicker-current-day"];
                    }

                    return [result];
                };

                this.options.datepickerOptions.onChangeMonthYear = function (year, month, datepicker) {

                }

                this.options.$datepicker.datepicker(this.options.datepickerOptions);
            };

            return FormBuilderDatePicker;
        })();
    }

    function setupQuoteModuleDatePicker() {
        var quoteModuleObjArr = [
            { formId: "quote-module-form-moving", className: '.zipcode-moving', moveType: 'moving' },
            { formId: "quote-module-form-storage", className: '.zipcode-storage', moveType: 'storage' },
            { formId: "quote-module-form-moving-storage", className: '.zipcode-moving-storage', moveType: 'moving-storage' }
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < quoteModuleObjArr.length; i++) {
            var formBuilder = null;
            formBuilder = new FormBuilderDatePicker({
                datepicker: '#' + quoteModuleObjArr[i].formId + ' input.isDatePicker',
                formId: '#' + quoteModuleObjArr[i].formId
            });

            greyOutFacilityClosedDates(quoteModuleObjArr[i].formId, quoteModuleObjArr[i].className, formBuilder, quoteModuleObjArr[i].moveType);

            //return formBuilder;
        }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for testing purposes the OP's above posted code was taken as is ... results/conclusion ...

- `FormBuilderDatePicker` exists as constructor function.
- `registerSelectors` exists as prototypal method.

There was another error within the code of the prototypal `delegateEvents` methods though ... `this.options.$datepicker.datepicker` ... of cause is not provided with the current environment (settings).

The OP's script got sanitized and (re)formatted  into the next provided example  code in order to provide proof that the OP's code actually does work. Thus there must be some other reasons for the OP's script failures.

```js
const dp = new FormBuilderDatePicker;

console.log({ registerSelectors: dp.registerSelectors });
console.log({ dp });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var FormBuilderDatePicker = (function () {

  function FormBuilderDatePicker(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaults, this.options);
    this.registerSelectors();
    this.delegateEvents();
  };

  FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.defaults = {
    datepicker: ".hasDatePicker",
    disabledDays: [],
    datepickerOptions: {
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "+12M",
    },
    formId: '',
  };
  FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.registerSelectors = function () {
    this.options.$datepicker = $(this.options.datepicker);
  };
  FormBuilderDatePicker.prototype.delegateEvents = function () {

    var _self = this;
    this.options.$datepicker.on("error", function () {
      var selectedDate = _self.options.$datepicker.val();
      _self.options.disabledDays.push(selectedDate);
    });
    this.options.$datepicker.on("change", function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });
    this.options.datepickerOptions.beforeShowDay = function (date) {

      var today = new Date;
      var todayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", today);
      var selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date);

      var notToday = todayDate != selectedDate;
      var isDisabledDay = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate("m/d/yy", date), _self.options.disabledDays) == -1;
      var result = notToday && isDisabledDay;

      if (notToday == false) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        }, 0);

        return [result, "ui-datepicker-current-day"];
      }
      return [result];
    };
    this.options.datepickerOptions.onChangeMonthYear = function (year, month, datepicker) {

    };
    // this.options.$datepicker.datepicker(this.options.datepickerOptions);
  };

  return FormBuilderDatePicker;
}());
</script>
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, I had a script failure. Working code applied to the original question. Thanks